# kendo grid headers disappear when resize & scroll horizontally RTL

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've a problem in kendo grid RTL version.

After resizing the columns and then scrolling horizontally, if you move the cursor over the header, the columns will move insanely or even disappear.

You can test it through the following link:
https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/right-to-left-support

How can I get it to work properly and as expected?

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: headers are not showed properly, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

[According to this post](https://feedback.telerik.com/kendo-jquery-ui/1487148-chrome-rtl-horizontal-scroll-grid-bugs), it appears Telerik is aware of the issue and are working on it. They also seem to indicate it is a Chrome specific issue due to a recent change of RTL handling:

> Thank you for taking the time to share the observations of the
> resizing in RTL. Indeed, we are aware of this issue and it was
> introduced with the newer versions of Chrome. The browser changed the
> way they handle RTL.
>
> What I can recommend is that you test the same example in other
> browsers and see if the issue persists. We would try to address this
> issue in the foreseeable future.